# Unknown number in crash report from Xcode Organizer

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

I am viewing crash report from Xcode Organizer for my app.

I saw "+ 92" in the following screenshot. What does it mean?

[image: xcode organizer crash report]

Answer (score 1):

This should be the position inside of the method where the error occurred. If you create your release archive with *Debug Information Format* **dwarf-with-dsym** Xcode can reproduce the line number in your source files with that information.